# How to redirect in axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Can I redirect in `.then` instead of `console.log`?

```
axios
  .post('/api/users/login', user)
  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data }))
```

Is it possible and if it is how can I do it?

Comment: redirect to another page or it is based on the response ?

Comment: i think your question is not an axios related one  .

you could use this => location.href

Comment: and reactjs tag is not relavant.

Comment: I just want to redirect to '/' after login

Comment: its not about reactjs or axios.
its just pure java script
you could use my solution ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you should not perform side operations inside the actions (in this case axios call). This is because you would eventually add these calls inside redux thunk/saga or some other middleware.

The pattern which I follow is you return the promise and add the redirection logic inside your components(or containers). Following are the benefits of it:-

1. It makes your code cleaner and avoids side affects inside your API calls.
2. It makes easier to test your API calls using mock data.
3. Showing alert in case the API fails without passing callback as function parameter.

Now, that being said you can use the above logic in following ways:-

```
// Component code

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class TestContainer extends React.Component {
  auth = () => {
    login()
    .then(() => {
      browserHistory.push("/addUser");
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // Show alert to user;
    })
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.auth}>Auth</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Action code 

const login = () => {
  return axios
  .post('/api/users/login', user);
}
```

Comment: I get the following error `Attempted import error: 'browserHistory' is not exported from 'react-router'.`

Answer (score 1):

U can use: location.window.href

Usually I use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to redirect

**history.js**

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory()
```

**Root.jsx**

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
<Router history={history}>
 <Route path="/test" component={Test}/>
</Router>
```

**another_file.js**

```
import history from './history' 

history.push('/test') // this should change the url and re-render Test component
```

Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3498

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about reactjs or axios, its just pure javascript.

Use `location.href`